# linking Credit card account with YodleeAPI

Tags: yodlee

We are getting MFA_INFO_NOT_PROVIDED_IN_REAL_TIME_BY_USER_VIA_APP while linking account with Yodlee API ,any one help to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

It means that you haven't provided MFA information within time.

Please check our API flow- https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/API_Flow/Add_Account_With_ProviderAccount

Also check our status codes-https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Status_Codes

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik

Comment: Thanks for your support